# Cannot mock the return value of a class instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a python unit test function as follows:

```
@mock.patch("helpers.Client")  # This is the class whose method I want to test
def test_client(mock_client):

    schema = some_hard_coded_dictionary
    client_instance = mock.MagicMock()
    client_instance.get_datasets.return_value = schema
    mock_client.return_value = client_instance

    some_call()
```

Now, when the call for `client.get_datasets` gets hits, it is something like:

```
dataset = client.get_datasets(dataset_id)
```

Here I expected dataset to be my hard coded dictionary but instead it is of type `<MagicMock name='Client().get_datasets()' id='4781712864'>`

**EDIT**

I am trying to create a replicable test case and am unable to do so. I tried this example and it works as expected:

```
class SomeClient(object):
    def __init__(self, base_url, another_param) -> None:
        self.url = base_url
        self.another_param = another_param

    def get_datasets(dataset_id):
        return {"A": "B"}


def some_call():
    client = SomeClient("URL", 3)
    datasets = client.get_datasets(1)
    pass


@mock.patch("mymodule.SomeClient")
def test_debug(mock_client):
    client_instance = mock.Mock()
    client_instance.get_datasets.return_value = {"C": "D"}
    mock_client.return_value = client_instance

    some_call()
```

I am even more confused now.

Comment: Could you turn this into a real working example that you can run and share the results of?  There's a typo in your code, and your output references `MagicMock` instead of `Mock`.  On first blush it looks like the approach you took should work, but I can't run the code and test it, and you obviously aren't running this actual code either.

Comment: You have already mocked `Client` (e.g. `mock_client`), so probably you have to  use that instead of a new `client_instance`. As I don't know what `mock_arte_client` is, I can't say for sure what you are doing.

Comment: All the interesting code appears to be in the undefined `some_call`. What is `client`?

Comment: Sorry I had changed some things and clearly my code did not update. Let me quickly create an example...

Comment: Ok, in this case `mock_client.return_value.get_datasets.return_value = schema` looks more like it.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen This still does the same. More bizarre, my simple replication test seems to work.

Comment: Well, without a replicable test it is difficult to say...

Comment: Well, figured it out. Replicable test works as I had only one decorator. I messed up the order of the decorators.